# Checkbuttons using dictionary will not update values

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, tkinter

Folks,

So I've been working on a little GUI using Tkinter for a capstone project, and given the circumstances, I've only been programming for about two weeks before I was thrown into this, so I'm still a newbie.

My issue today is that I cannot manage to get my checkbutton dictionary to update values; the output for my checkbutton is always 0 or False. The code is as follows:

```
...

datatype= {'Joint Angle' : 0,
     'Joint Acceleration' : 0,
     'Ground Reaction Force' : 0,
     'Muscle Activation' : 0
}

for measure in datatype:
    datatype[measure] = IntVar()
    dt_cb = Checkbutton(root, text=measure,
                    variable=datatype[measure],command = enable_location_state)
dt_cb.grid(column=0, sticky='W', padx=20)


dt1 = datatype['Joint Angle'].get()
dt2 = datatype['Joint Acceleration'].get()
dt3 = datatype['Ground Reaction Force'].get()
dt4 = datatype['Muscle Activation'].get()
...
```

So I tried periodically printing values throughout the code and I continued to get 0 as soon as I booted the GUI, and after that, no matter what I clicked, the numbers did not update. I read that I should try BooleanVar() and StringVar() instead, but neither of those worked. The code is based off of another bit of code I found somewhere on stackoverflow, though I cannot remember exactly where.

I tried making it a list rather than a dictionary in order to overcome my problem because I was successful with lists previously, but the list created only a single checkbutton for all of those and I was unable to differentiate what is what.

The command enable_location_state configures other checkbuttons, and is as follows:

```
def enable_location_state():

    if dt1 == 1 or dt2 == 1:
        ja_cb.configure(state=ACTIVE)

    if dt3 == 1:
        grf_cb.configure(state=ACTIVE)

    if dt4 == 1:
        emg_cb.configure(state=ACTIVE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are getting the values of the `IntVar` only once: at the same moment you create your buttons. Move your `.get()` statements to the beginning of the `enable_location_state()` function. That way, every time your checkbutton is clicked, the function will check on (i.e., `.get()`) the value of the `IntVar`.